# $base_url not working when in anchor link to theme folder

Tags: uri

e.g. this:

```
<a href="<?php echo $front_page; ?>" title="<?php echo t('Home');?>" rel="home" id="logo">
        <img src="http://localhost/jamesbondblog/sites/all/themes/jamestheme/images/logo.jpg">
</a>
```

is working.

But this is not:

```
<a href="<?php echo $front_page; ?>" title="<?php echo t('Home');?>" rel="home" id="logo">
        <img src="<?php echo $base_url; ?>/sites/all/themes/jamestheme/images/logo.jpg">
</a>
```

Can someone explain why?

I am using Drupal 7 and this code is in page.tpl.php

Comment: What is your output for whats not working Q?

Comment: I have solved it meanwhile by myself: instead of <?php echo $base_url; ?> I need to use <?php global $base_url; echo $base_url; ?>

Comment: Can I ask why is this global variable not accessible by default? For security reasons? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wasnt aware this was available to the page template which is probably why you couldnt get it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about  `global $base_path;` ?

Comment: perfect ;). it's working and without any errors in admin!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

In your themes template...

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
   global $base_url;
   $variables['base_url'] = $base_url;
}
```

In page template...

```
$base_url;
```

Comment: This way echo $base_url; outputs nothing. You have soething wrong with your code probably. But at least the message in admin of undefined variable dissappeared ;)

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED (with an error message in admin :(**

Instead of `<?php echo $base_url; ?>`

you need to use `<?php global $base_url; echo $base_url; ?>`

But it keeps saying in my modules this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: base_url in include() (line 9 of C:\wamp\www\jamesbondblog\sites\all\themes\jamestheme\page.tpl.php).
```

Thanks in advance for a fix to get rid of this error message.

Comment: This isnt the way to go Q...

Comment: You can see what variables are available to page template. Go to /includes/theme.inc line: 2516

Comment: I know it's wrong, but it is working in the template. Your way is outputing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$GLOBALS['base_url']` instead, for example:

```
<img src="<?= $GLOBALS['base_url'] ?>/sites/all/themes/foo/images/logo.jpg">
```